# How can I set a different size for my circle icon only? (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio

I designed an icon for my app today, and it looks good on everything but the circle icon shape. If I try to make it small enough for it to look okay, my icon looks too small for every other icon shape. Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could have a different resize level for just the circle icon?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Android Studio doesn't allow separating between square and rounded icons, this will not be a straightforward:

**You can do it in two stages:**

1. **Step 1:** With Asset Studio, design squared icons with the size you want >> You already did this step
2. **Step 2:** Right Click on Mipmap from the Project navigator pane -> Show in Explorer -> Copy all mipmap dpi drawable variations into a
   backup location.
3. **Step 3:** In each drawable variation, remove the rounded drawable version.
4. **Step 4:** Same as in step 1; design rounded icons with the desired size, and save it.
5. **Step 5:** Copy the backed-up drawables you got from Step no.3, and then paste them on your app's location `..\app\src\main\res` and
   accept replacement.